# TypeError: 'this.validator is not a function' on complete not releated error callback

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here is the stack trace:

```
 TypeError: this.validator is not a function            app.component.ts:35
  at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2720)
  at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2688)
  at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:3011)
  at FormBuilder.control (forms.es5.js:5863)
  at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.es5.js:5905)
  at eval (forms.es5.js:5887)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.es5.js:5886)
  at FormBuilder.group (forms.es5.js:5845)
  at ProfileSettingsComponent.init (profile-settings.component.ts:318)
```

I got this error when open user setting page. As you can see in the stack trace  on line 318 in profile-settings.componenet.ts, there is just the first line of FormBuilder. And i can't understand what's the relation between the FormBuilder and getting user object in app.componenet.ts.

app.component.ts:

```
this.sub = this.userService.getLoggedUser()
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.info('From app: ', res.body.user);
    this.loadVideoChatInviter = true;
  }, err => {
    console.error(err); // line 35
  });
```

profile-settings.component.ts:

```
this.userSettingsToUpdate = this.fb.group({ // line 318
  'firstName': this.user.firstName,
  'lastName': this.user.lastName,
  'email': this.user.email,
  'gender': this.genderItems,
  // ... 
  'newPassword': ['', Validators.minLength(6)],
  'confirmedPassword': ['', Validators.minLength(6)],
  // ...
});
```

Comment: show the code where you used `validator`

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: @IliyanIvanov can you share `import && constructor` code

Comment: refer [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example)

Comment: @Abhishek from which componenet? The constructors is empty in both components.

Comment: @IliyanIvanov you have to use `private fb: FormBuilder` in `profile-settings.component.ts`

Comment: @IliyanIvanov if have create stackblitz than it is helpful for both its save much tym to solve problem

Comment: I have private fb: FormBuilder injected in constructor. And I think I have found the problem. It is because of angular2-multiselect with config 'singleSelection: true' who had binded to array with more than 1 value.